# ¿Cómo puedo hacer de estas consultas una sola?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo mi primera consulta la cual me trae el total de *temas* que tiene cada *curso* :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) total_temas
FROM temas 
GROUP BY temas.curso_id

id  curso_id    total_temas     
6       4           7
11      5           2
17      6           1
```

Y mi siguiente consulta trae los datos de otra tabla llamada *avance*, que cuenta los temas que ya vio el usuario:

```
SELECT avance.curso_id, cursos.curso_nombre, usuarios1.nombre, 
usuarios1.ap_p, avance.usuario_id, 
COUNT(*) as temas_vistos
FROM avance
INNER JOIN cursos ON cursos.curso_id = avance.curso_id
INNER JOIN usuarios1 ON usuarios1.id = avance.usuario_id
GROUP BY avance.usuario_id, avance.curso_id;

curso_id    curso_nombre    nombre        ap_p  usuario_id  temas_vistos    
   4            Test    Estudiante         A_P     2             2
   4            Test    Estudiante No. 2   AP      3             6
   5            Excel   Estudiante No. 2   AP      3             2 
   6            Word    Estudiante No. 2   AP      3             1
   4            Test    Estudiante No. 3   XV      5             3
```

Mi propósito es realizar la operación del promedio con los temas totales y los que están en *avance* y mostrarlos en gráfica.
Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1) Crea una vista sobre tu consulta 1:

```
create view vresumen(id,curso_id,total_temas) as    
SELECT *, COUNT(*) total_temas
FROM temas 
GROUP BY temas.curso_id
```

Una vez creada la vista, la puedes incluir en tu consulta 2, como si se tratase de una tabla más.

```
SELECT avance.curso_id, cursos.curso_nombre, usuarios1.nombre, 
usuarios1.ap_p, avance.usuario_id, vresumen.total_temas,
COUNT(*) as temas_vistos
FROM avance
INNER JOIN cursos ON cursos.curso_id = avance.curso_id
INNER JOIN usuarios1 ON usuarios1.id = avance.usuario_id
JOIN vresumen on vresumen.curso_id=cursos.curso_id
GROUP BY avance.usuario_id, avance.curso_id,vresumen.total_temas;
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias! Funciona bien.